# JSON-конфиги в тестах

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-нибудь общепринятые практики для удобного использования конфигов в тестах? Что я имею в виду: есть один конфиг для работы всего приложения, и есть тесты на это приложение. В тестах, чтобы проверить все случаи, я создаю строку с конфигом, формирую из неё JSON-конфиг, и далее сам тест. Но, при добавлении нового параметра в конфиг, приходится править все строки в тестах, так как каждый параметр должен быть задан. Довольно накладно получается.

Если что, использую RadidJSON и Google Tests.

Заранее спасибо!